# Magento 2.1.7 product page 404 after migration

Tags: magento-2.1, migration, 404, luma-theme

I migrated all of the data from a Magento 1.9 build to Magento 2.1.7 everything has gone well. categories are showing, products are in the categories, product images are showing on backend and category pages, all settings have migrated.

However I have one issue, every single product page when clicking from the category returns the Magento 404 and the product pages don't seem to exist, still using `luma` base theme for testing.

Debug/exception/error logs show nothing.

[image: category page product showing fine]
The category image/text above links to the following URL:

domain-name.com/basins/express-corner-basin-and-pedestal

as expected as per the Magento 1 build.

When editing the product in the backend:

[image]

I've `re-indexed/cleared cache/ran magento:upgrade`. At the end of my knowledge of what could be causing this - has anyone had this issue/have any suggestions on what to try next?

**EDIT:** Manually added a new product through the admin panel - same result 404 error page, shows in category fine.

Comment: check like : domain-name.com/catalog/product/view/id/{product-id}, still there is 404

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. same result 404 magento error page.

Comment: There is any product content display or 404 page content display there .

Comment: Just magentos 404 whoops page: https://i.imgur.com/HUPVqSU.png @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: Also check with product is enabled,have qty , in stock and in magento1 there is not given specific theme to that product from design tab

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. https://i.imgur.com/WkmU4pg.png enabled/in stock/ qty.  Design settings: https://i.imgur.com/JmGiK6Y.png

Comment: Design settings:  you have to check in magneto1

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. oh sorry - https://i.imgur.com/T3zvfoU.png

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. added a new product via admin panel and that product shows in category but links to the same 404 error. I'm so confused.

Comment: check with domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/product-id

Comment: @SunilPatel tried that above, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try go to configuration and disable the category in the product URL path, then reindex, see if product pages work. If this works, try setting it back and Reindex again.

Comment: Disabled the category in the product url. Still same result 404 magento whoops.

Comment: You may have some issues with URL rewrites. I had a few and ended up truncating the rewrite table. Backup before you try!

Comment: just to be clear all you did was truncate the rewrite tables (catalog_url_rewrite_product_category and URL_rewrite) then run reindex via ssh?

Comment: Yes. And clear /pub/static

Answer (score -1):

Please check all product entity(Ids) available in "**sequence_product**" table.
Need product id in that table to init product page.